# Make text wrap in a cell with FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Right now when I use a cell with text, it all stays on one line. I know I could use the write function, but I want to be able to specify the height and width.

This is what I have now, but as I said the text does not wrap to stay in the dimensions:

```
$pdf->Cell( 200, 40, $reportSubtitle, 1, 1 );
```

Comment: I think tutorial #6 covers this: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Text Wrap:

The `MultiCell` is used for print text with multiple lines. It has the same atributes of `Cell` except for `ln` and `link`.

```
$pdf->MultiCell( 200, 40, $reportSubtitle, 1);
```

---

### Line Height:

What multiCell does is to spread the given text into multiple cells, this means that the second parameter defines the height of each line (individual cell) and not the height of all cells (collectively).

> MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])

You can read the full documentation [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm).

Comment: @PHPDeveloper & others see this: [line break problem with MultiCell in FPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1419719/1544337) - this explains how to put cells next to a MultiCell.

Comment: This page shows a good example of how to use it in a table: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php

Comment: MultiCell is useless, if you want a few cells - one next to each other - try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30359325/436443

Comment: What about the `ln` parameter? Should it be explicitly given after MultiCell?