# FPDF: Change text color while inside a Cell?

Tags: php, text, colors, cell, fpdf

I want it so that the text saying white will use SetTextColor as white, and the orange to use orange.

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Cell(50,0,'WHITE ORANGE ORANGE WHITE',0,1,'C');
```

How do I affect the 'ORANGE' words to use an orange text color?

Comment: Can't this link give a clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477372/make-text-wrap-in-a-cell-with-fpdf

Comment: But I'm confused by this as I still would like it to stay on one line. I'm looking at making a visual difference for the text color only. Maybe I misread something.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible with a little trick. I just made it printing 2 Cells, one over the other, like this:

```
//Setting the text color to black
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

//Printing my cell      
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B');
$pdf->Cell(55,5,"Black Text ",1,0,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($coordXbase,$coordY);

//Setting the text color to red
$pdf->SetTextColor(194,8,8);

//Printing another cell, over the other
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B');
//Give some space from the left border, and print the red text after the black text that is in the cell behind this one.
$pdf->Cell(55,5,"                        Red Text",0,0,'C');
$pdf->SetXY($coordXbase,$coordY);

//Setting the text color back to back, in the next cells.
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
```

The result was this:

[image: Multicollor cell result]

As I was a little rush, I had no time to create some function to help with this, but this would be a good starting point idea :)

P.S.: Tell if you guys find an easier way.

Answer (score 5):

I needed that functionality too. This is the function I written to do a simple colored string:

```
function cellMultiColor($stringParts) {
    $currentPointerPosition = 0;
    foreach ($stringParts as $part) {
        // Set the pointer to the end of the previous string part
        $this->_pdf->SetX($currentPointerPosition);

        // Get the color from the string part
        $this->_pdf->SetTextColor($part['color'][0], $part['color'][1], $part['color'][2]);

        $this->_pdf->Cell($this->_pdf->GetStringWidth($part['text']), 10, $part['text']);

        // Update the pointer to the end of the current string part
        $currentPointerPosition += $this->_pdf->GetStringWidth($part['text']);
    }
```

and you use it like this:

```
cellMultiColor([
    [
        'text' => 'Colored string example: ',
        'color' => [0, 0, 0],
    ],
    [
        'text' => 'red',
        'color' => [255, 0, 0],
    ],
    [
        'text' => ', ',
        'color' => [0, 0, 0],
    ],
    [
        'text' => 'blue',
        'color' => [0, 0, 255],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

IF you don't need to use the Cell method, you could use the Write method instead:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','b',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(153,0,153);
$pdf->Write(7,'Text in color, ');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Write(7,'and text in black all in the same line'));
$pdf->Ln(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar thing. Instead of color I had to change the size of the font.
in my cell I called the function instead
so,in your case you  can do this

```
$pdf->Cell(50,0,white($pdf,'White').orange($pdf,'orange'),0,1,'C');
```

and define the function as

```
function white($pdf,$val){
              $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
              return $pdf->Text(0,0,$val);
              }
```

and same goes for orange.

TIP: to position it properly use getX() and getY()

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work for me... how would you use getX() and getY() to color a word somewhere in a centered line, as in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1: You can't. A cell by definition is uniform in font and color. You can measure the width of the words with getStringWidth and do it in a series of Cells.

Answer #2: Many of the contributed scripts are based on constructing variants of built-in functions. After all, you have the PHP code right there for all of FPDF. You can make your own Cell_plus function that takes an array of phrases and another array or two or three of attributes. Then maybe contribute it as an additional script.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a `writeHTML` method (tcpdf ver 6.2) like so

```
$html = 'Simple text <span style="color: rgb(255,66,14);">Orange</span> simple  <span style="color: rgb(12,128,128);">Turquoise</span>';
$this->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Answer (score -1):

You should replace this:

```
$pdf->Cell(50,0,'WHITE ORANGE ORANGE WHITE',0,1,'C');
```

for this

```
$pdf->Cell(50,0,'WHITE ORANGE ORANGE WHITE',0,1,'C', true);
```

//Add the true param  at the end