# How can I automatically adjust text in a cell in FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I’m using FPDF with PHP to generate reports. When the text is too long, it overflows. How can I stop this?

```
$string = "IT IS TOO LONG IT IS TOO LONG IT IS TOO LONG IT IS TOO LONG IT IS TOO LONG IT IS TOO LONG";
       $pdf->Cell(190,10,'Observations: '.$string.'',0,0,'C');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make text wrap in a cell with FPDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477372/make-text-wrap-in-a-cell-with-fpdf)

Comment: Thanks it was MultiCell