# how to auto adjust cell width in fpdf using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have a problem in creating table structure in pdf using fpdf library. when any data of perticular cell have a long string then the cell data will overlap with other cell data..
 auto adjust cell width in fpdf... plz help me...

My code:

```
                <?php
    require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    //Connect to your database
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mus');

            /*
            * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
            */
            if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

    //Create new pdf file
    $pdf=new FPDF();

    //Open file
    $pdf->Open();

    //Disable automatic page break
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

    //Add first page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    //set initial y axis position per page
    $y_axis_initial = 25;

    //print column titles for the actual page
    $pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->Cell(10, 6, 'CODE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'NAME', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $row_height = 6;
    $y_axis = $y_axis_initial + $row_height;

    //Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
    $sql = 'SELECT WaiterPckey, WaiterName, WaiterShortName FROM `waitermaster`';
    $result= $mysqli->query($sql); 

    //initialize counter
    $i = 0;

    //Set maximum rows per page
    $max = 25;

    //Set Row Height
    ;

    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
    {
        //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
        if ($i == $max)
        {
            $pdf->AddPage();

            //print column titles for the current page
            $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
            $pdf->SetX(4);
            $pdf->Cell(10, 6, 'CODE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'NAME', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);

            //Go to next row
            $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

            //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
            $i = 0;
        }

        $code = $row[0];
        $price = $row[1];
        $name = $row[2];

        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetX(5);
        $pdf->Cell(10, 6, $code, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 6, $name, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(40, 6, $price, 1, 0, 'L', 1);

        //Go to next row
        $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
        $i = $i + 1;
    }


    //Create file
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
    ?>
```

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477372/make-text-wrap-in-a-cell-with-fpdf

Answer (score 4):

Use **string** width for cell with

```
$string = fullname($USER);
$cellWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($string);
$pdf->Cell($cellWidth + 5, 0, $string, 0, 0, 'C', true);
```

String width doc http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/getstringwidth.htm

Cell docs http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use table with multicell to solve the issue of dynamic width and height.And click this link to see the example of plugin [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php).This will be very much useful for
dynamic width and height.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use this code. You must require mysql_table.php tho.

Define the column first, the size, the name and the align
AddCol (<the name of column in mysql table>, <column size>, <the name you preferred>, <align>)
then you can print the table.
If you think that the first column is smaller, set it to 10 etc.

```
$pdf->AddCol('code',20,'CODE','C');
$pdf->AddCol('name',40,'NAME');
$pdf->AddCol('price',40,'PRICE','R');
$pdf->Table('-----PUT YOUR SQL QUERY----');
$pdf->Output();
```

[Check it here!](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to solve this problem... 
here the concept is only if string size greater than your cell width then font size will reduce.

**Note that you can not use this code for a multi-line string. for this, you have to use MultiCell()**

```
    $pdf = new FPDFCellFit();
    $pdf->FPDF('P','mm','A4');
    $pdf->SetMargins(15,15,15);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
    $pdf->AliasNbPages('{nb}');

    $pdf->isFooter = true ;
    $pdf->footerSchool=$college->COLLEGE_NAME;

    $BodyX=15;$BodyY=25;

    $table_head1=array(25,46,40,20,60);
    $table_head2=array(25,20,26,20,20,16,24,40);
    // some code remove from here for show actual code.
    $pdf->CellFit($table_head2[7],$table_height,$item['remark'],1,0,'C',0,'',1,0);
```

[image]

> check 20-Jan-2020 line for this solution.