# How to auto resize the cell in fpdf using php

Tags: php

I need to  auto adjust the cell size depends upon the text . I have the following code .

```
$pdf->Cell(50,10,$name,1,0,'L',0);
```

If the `$name` exceed 10 character means the `$name` wrap into the next cell. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I refer to: [GetStringWidth](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/getstringwidth.htm) and [SetFont](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm). As pointed out there, to use this method, a font must be selected. So I assume, you already have something like:

```
.
.
$pdf->AddPage();

$fontFamily = 'Courier'; // 'Courier', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Times', 'Symbol', 'ZapfDingbats'
$fontStyle = 'B'; // 'B', 'I', 'U', 'BI', 'BU', 'IU', 'BIU'
$fontSize = 12.0; // float, in point

$pdf->SetFont($fontFamily, $fontStyle, $fontSize);
```

To adjust the cell width to the length of the text, let its value take the calculated length of the text:

```
$width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($name);
$height = 10.0;
$border = 1;
$ln = 0;
$align = 'L';
$fill = FALSE;

$pdf->Cell($width, $height, $name, $border, $ln, $align, $fill);
```

Havn't tested it, just read the manual. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to solve this problem... here the concept is only if string size greater than your cell width then font size will reduce.

```
$pdf->CellFit($table_head2[7],$table_height,$item['remark'],1,0,'C',0,'',1,0);
```

check this URL

[how to auto adjust cell width in fpdf using php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603371/how-to-auto-adjust-cell-width-in-fpdf-using-php-and-mysql)