# FPDF Table cell wrap

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, word-wrap

I Created a table with FPDF and I want to wrap the word in the cells(table).
this is my code .

```
$w = array(7, 150, 40);
$pdf->Cell($w[0], 6, $count, 'LR');
$pdf->Cell($w[1], 6, $column_heading, 'LR');
$pdf->Cell($w[2], 6, $rekey, 'LR', 0, 'R');

$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
$count++;
```

This is out put of the code how can I break the text in cells.

[image]

Comment: FPDF requires manual computation for the position of cells as far as I remember, (or just adjust the height of the cell based on the number of characters inside it.. XD)

Comment: @catzilla that means ??

Comment: it means that when creating individual cells, the height of the cell should be adjusted as well.. ( if h is 4 for one line, change to 8 for lines)

Comment: @catzilla how can i do that ? any example ?

Comment: I'll compose an answer, a moment.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make text wrap in a cell with FPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477372/make-text-wrap-in-a-cell-with-fpdf)

Comment: @usr2564301 It didnt work

Answer (score 0):

FPDF prints the cells and the text separately (means that it's like 2 layers)

from manual: http://www.fpdf.org/

```
Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
```

Suggested Approach:

context length should be computed code-wise, if the content is greater than the allotted cell width then it should be divided and transferred to a new line.

At the same time cell height `h` should be adjusted (increase in height).

As I remember (fpdf experts can correct me) automatic adjustment of cells based on content is not yet implemented as a feature of the library.

**Correction**: there is http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: Cannot create table with multicell

Comment: Then I think you can try my suggested approach.. :)
I also encountered similar issues with you

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use multicell, you could try shrinking the text until it fits in the cell by getting the string width.

**example:**

```
//loop the data
foreach($data as $item){
    $pdf->Cell(10, 5,$item[0],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(60, 5,$item[1],1,0);

    //shrink font size until it fits the cell width
    while($pdf->getStringWidth($item[2]) > $cellWidth){// loop until the string width is smaller than cell width
        $pdf->SetFontSize($tempFontSize -= 0.1);
    }
    $pdf->Cell($cellWidth,5,$item[2],1,0);
    //reset font size to standard
    $tempFontSize = $fontSize;
    $pdf->SetFontSize($fontSize);

    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$item[3],1,1);
}
```